# Converting .Net Famework WCF Project to .Net 6 With Custom Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf

I have spent several days on this project. We have a .Net Framework 4.7.2 WCF project in our solution that we want to convert to the newest .Net6. I used the upgrade assistant to refactor the code to .Net 6. When the upgrade assistant was finished, I only had 1 error, which I fixed easily. I ran the project and it loaded up and was listening. But we cannot call the API because .Net core is not compatible with Config files. I guess specifically, it is not compatible with the app.config.

I think I need to take all of the values from the app.config and enter them into appsettings. I have already done that. I believe the next thing I need to do is create the client using the values that were in the app.config and are now in the appsettings file. This is where I am stuck.

I discovered https://github.com/CoreWCF. I thought I was going to be able to use that to create a client and connect to our service, but the documentation is poor. Here is my configuration.

See the relevant section of my app.config below.

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="XXXX" sendTimeout="00:06:00">
    <transactionFlow />
    <security   defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" 
                allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" 
                enableUnsecuredResponse="true" 
                authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" 
                requireDerivedKeys="false" 
                messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" 
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" 
                requireSignatureConfirmation="false" />
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="egwBehavior">
    <clientCredentials>
      <clientCertificate    findValue="CN=XXX, OU=XXX, O=XXX, L=XXX, S=XX, C=XX" 
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
      <serviceCertificate>
        <defaultCertificate findValue="CN=XXX, SERIALNUMBER=XXX, OID.0.0.0.05=XXX, O=XXX, OID.0.0.0=XX, L=XX, S=XX, C=XX" 
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                            storeName="TrustedPeople" 
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
        <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" 
                        revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        <sslCertificateAuthentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
      </serviceCertificate>
      <windows allowNtlm="false" />
    </clientCredentials>
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

I believe I need to use those properties from my app.config, shown above to create objects that are used to create the client connection, but I don't know where to begin.

I am also new to WCF. If someone could help get me started I would appreciate is. I just need to know how to create client and handle the binding.

I know I should show my code, and I will do it, but it's a mess. It kind of demonstrates what I have tried.

```
public EGClient(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Type contractType = typeof(egw);
    Type implementedContract = typeof(egwClient);

    var identity = new DnsEndpointIdentity("xx.xx.com");
    var uri = new Uri(configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceEndpoint"));
    ServiceEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri, identity);

    ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(implementedContract, uri);

    binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
    var cert = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();
    cert.TrustedStoreLocation  = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
    cert.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
    cert.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
    X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential clientCredential = new X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential( );
    clientCredential.SetCertificate("CN=xx.xx.com, O= xxx, C=US", StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.TrustedPeople);
    cert.

    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding.Name = "egwSoap";
    binding.Namespace = "MyService";
    //var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);
    //var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService>(binding, endpoint);
    //channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatepath, password);

    //_client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

    //var sbmtGtDtResp = _client.ExternalServiceOperation(data);
}
```

Thanks for your help.